# Do we get more information about Rose and Paige's necklaces?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In the opening scene of *The Last Jedi* we see the bombing run of the resistance take out the First Order Dreadnought. The only bomber who manages to destroy it is Paige, who holds onto a necklace before doing one more kick to knock the detonator down.

[image: The necklace]

While we later see Rose has the same necklace (or one that fits together with it), that's used as a conductor of some kind to open a door.

However given the 3-4 second shot we get at the start of the necklace, Paige hold onto it as if it had some sort of power, and then find the courage to kick the detonator down, but after that point the necklace only features as a minor point as a measly conductor.

Was the purpose simply to show they were sisters? Do we ever learn more about the necklace?

Comment: I think the idea of the necklace is what Rose says later. They get more strength from love than hate. Hating the First Order didn't get the job done, but the idea of saving her sister and the fleet did. Which follows from RotJ where Luke and Vader used love to overcome hatred and evil.

Comment: That was her sister? I missed that. I assumed they were girl friends. I did think she took a shine to Finn awfully fast for somebody still mourning the loss of her GF.

Comment: @nedlud I'm almost certain in the film she says it's her sister.

Answer (score 11):

There's some info about them in the film's [Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary) and other factbooks. In short, Paige and Rose are sisters and the matched necklaces were made for them by their parents out of an ore that was found on their (now First Order dominated) home colony.

> **ROSE'S MEDALLION**
>
> *Rose's medallion is a stylised ensign of the Otomok system,
>   representing Hays Minor. It is made of pure Haysian smelt, a
>   transition metal with incredibly efficient conductive properties. It
>   is the partner medallion of the one worn by Paige Tico.*

It also mentions that her home system of Otomok came to be dominated by the First Order and numerous children abducted to make into stormtroopers, hence her fond desire to do them some damage and why she (and her sister) find the necklaces such an inspiration.

[image]

The medallions, according to the factbook [Rose Tyco: Resistance Fighter](http://The%20Last%20Jedi:%20Rose%20Tico:%20Resistance%20Fighter), are a matched set, cast together in the same mould at the same time by their prospector parents.

[image]

There's also some relevant info in [The Last Jedi: Bomber Command](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Last_Jedi:_Bomber_Command).

[image]

---

From a filmmaking perspective, I suspect that it was a lazy shorthand to let viewers know that these two characters are directly connected to each other. Note that a similar plot device is used later in the film with Rey and Leia's twinned transmitters.

Comment: Do something about it - kill abducted children :)

Comment: @rs.29 - Sometimes you need to destroy a village to save it.

Comment: Sometimes you need to destroy Resistance to save it :)

Comment: I always thought the two matched like a ying-yang symbol, with the large circular part going into the space made by the tail.

Comment: @SGR - I played with them for a while and even assuming the scale is slightly off (with one being 10-20% larger than the other), there's no combination where they align to make a completely filled circle; https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilYeS.png

Comment: Okay, I'll bite. What's particularly "lazy" about using a non-verbal clue to indicate that the two non-lead characters are tied together? Wouldn't "efficient" be a better choice of words?

Comment: @mattdm - Having two connected characters have matching jewellery is lazy because there are a thousand more subtle ways to show that same connection, not least actually casting real siblings.